# Implementing function interfaces defined inside record syntax?

Tags: function, haskell, types

I'm covering the reader monad at the moment, and I've come across `runReader`:

```
newtype Reader e a = Reader {runReader :: (e -> a)}
```

I understand that here the data constructor `Reader` is enabling two different types (`e` and `a`) to be passed into the type constructor `Reader` that uses record syntax to contain a function `runReader ::` that operates on `e` and `a`.

I'm trying implement a test of this:

```
newtype Test a b = Test {runTest :: (a -> b)}
```

How do I go about creating the implementation of `runTest`?

Comment: As you would for any other data type - pass it an argument of the right type! `Test id :: Test a a`, `Test (\b -> if b then Nothing else Just ()) :: Test Bool (Maybe ())`, etc.

Comment: @Alec this comment isn't constructive -- can you please explain??

Comment: I apologize if I came off as disingenuous, that wasn't the intention. My point was that even if `runTest` is peculiarly named, it still is just a field - to construct a `Test`, you pass it a function (to fill the `runTest` field). That function is your "implementation" of `runTest`.

Comment: @Alec that helps thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
t :: Test a b
```

then what is the type of

```
runTest t :: ?
```

Well, yes, `runTest t :: a -> b`. It is effectively the same as a function from `a` to `b`. Likewise, `Reader e a` is effectively a function with an `e` as its first argument.

You asked about implemenation, I'm assuming you mean how to implement the Reader Monad? Reader's monad implementation lets you compose multiple functions who all have `e` as their first argument, and handles distributing a single `e` to all those first inputs. The `e` supplied will be the input to your function `(runReader r) :: e -> a`

I'm not sure if I'm running off track here, let me know and I'll flesh out the reader monad a little.